# How can we achieve 360 Deg Scrolling functionality in any direction with ScrollView React Native?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, pinchzoom, react-native-scrollview, panresponder

I have a scenario in which I have to move my **ScrollView in any direction** as the user tries to scroll.

```
onContentSizeChange
```

I have read about it this function but I am unable to achieve the scrolling functionality in any direction. Can anybody help me in implementing the scroll view in this way?

Or Anybody have an idea of `Pand Responders` to achieve this functionality.

Thanks